# How to select multiple columns from many tables in a single query in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

I am writing function to search multiple columns from many tables like users table and product tables,here is how i am trying

```
Route::post ( '/search', function () {
$q = Input::get ( 'q' );
$user = DB::table('users')->where ( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->orWhere ( 'email', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->get ();
if (count ( $user ) > 0)
    return view ( 'welcome' )->withDetails ( $user )->withQuery ( $q );
else
    return view ( 'welcome' )->withMessage ( 'No Details found. Try to search again !' );
```

this is only for selecting many columns but only one table which is users table, but i have another table which is product tables and product_name column is there. So i want to include it in search query. which method should i use, aggregate method or union method? i tried some possible methods, but no luck yet. Please guide me.Thanks.

Comment: If they have no relationship, then a union would work fine.

Comment: yes, there is no relationship

Comment: As `->get()` returns a collection you can perform a completely separate query and merge the collections there after if you want. Alternatively, you can use a union, or so many other methods.

Comment: multiple columns or multiple rows ?

Comment: can u post a quick example please, i tried union method, not luck yet, thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Ravi multiple columns like product_name column(from products table),name,email columns(from users table)

Comment: @ThanHtutOo union would help you in that case..also you can take advantage of eager loading.. try UrModel::with(['table1','table2'..])->get()

Comment: @ThanHtutOo i guess i read question wrongly..u have to use union if they are not related.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something. (i have assumed some points as you have user with id 1 and product with id 1)

1) Union Method:

```
$users= \App\User::FindOrFail(1);
$productsWithUsers = \App\Products::where(['id'=>1])->union($table1)->get();
```

Now $productsWithUsers have all the columns from User and Product